# how to convert decimal to time in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am making an excel sheet in which I have calculated a value which comes up to be 27. I want to convert this number in hours such that its format becomes 27:00 hours. Can someone tell me how can I do this conversion.

Comment: Use custom format `[hh]:mm` to show hour values greater than 24h.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a day , we have just 24 hrs. not sure why are you trying for 27?
BTW ,Here you go:

> Enter the decimal value to cell. 
> To change the cell format use
>   keyboard shortcut Ctrl+1 to bring up the Format Cells dialog box
>   select the Number tab
> click Custom , then select the [h]:mm or [h]:mm:ss

Comment: There is indeed a scenario for values above 24 hours. E.g. If you want to show up durations let's say: A process runs already for 27 hours and 12 minutes you can write it like `27:12`.

Comment: The sheet computes total hours for a month thats why its exceeding 24.
The format "**[h]:mm:ss**" worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Well not actually. Using the type 'time' only allowed me to work in  a frame of 24 hours . As soon as it went beyond 24 it started back from 0:00
I used the type 'custom' and selected [h]:mm from it, which worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

you have to divide 27 by 24 and then you can apply this format [h]:mm;@
27/24=1.125
1.125 with the format looks like this 17:00